# update / edit function in django one-to-one models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i've made an edit form in django, and i have trouble in my update function. There is a relational models that using one-to-one relationship. When i run this function, data in User models stored properly, but not in the UserProfile models.

This is my urls.py

```
url(r'^update_user/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.update_user, name='update_user'),
```

This is my models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('admin','Admin'),
        ('user','User'),
        )
    hak_akses = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

This is my views.py

```
def update_user(request, pk, template_name='form_user.html'):
    related = User.objects.select_related().all()
    user = get_object_or_404(related, pk=pk)
   # profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=pk)
    if request.POST:
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST, instance=user)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=user)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()
            return redirect('manajemen_user')

    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=user)

    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is my forms:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('admin','Admin'),
        ('user','User'),
        )
    hak_akses = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('hak_akses',)
```

And this is my form templates html:

```
<form name="tambah_user" class="form-horizontal style-form" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">

              <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Nama User</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <!-- <input type="text" class='form-control'> -->
                {{ user_form.username }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ user_form.password }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Hak Akses</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ profile_form.hak_akses }}
                <br><br><br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

1. why data in User Models updated properly but not in UserProfile models ?
2. what's the solution?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should construct `UserProfileForm` form with the `UserProfile` instance instead of `User`:

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=user).first()
...
profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=profile)
...
profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
```

If you are sure that profile is already exist then you can write:

```
profile = user.userprofile
```

instead of the `filter().first()` call.

Comment: thank you very much sir. It works. I don't know what must i write on profile. Now i understand. thank you sir. ^__^

truly i still confused about django orm. Thats maybe a newbie problems like me. thanks.